# How to switch modal windows using Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have two modal windows ("register" and "login") and I show them using Twitter Bootstrap.

Now I need these behavior: window "login" is visible, it have button "Register", which must to close window "login" and show window "register".

a) Is it possible without manual Javascript code?

b) How I can to close windows manually?

```
$('login').modal('hide');
```

is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this http://jsfiddle.net/bbAsC/ ??

Two buttons, register and login - two modals respectively, if you click on "register" in the login modal, it closes login and shows register instead.

Markup

```
<a href="#login" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Login</a>
<a href="#register" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Register</a>

<!-- Modals -->
<div id="login" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3>Login</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>body</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="login-register">Register</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="register" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3>Register</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>body</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

script

```
$("#login-register").click(function() {
    $("#login").modal('hide');
    $("#register").modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

a) What you want to accomplish requires some (simple) javascript/jquery.

```
$("#next").click(function(){
    $('#firstModal').modal('hide');
    $('#secondModal').modal('show');
});​
```

See the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/QgNK8/) for the full markup. A more advanced version would probably want to use a callback on the #firstModal hide step (possibly by using the [.on technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821865/twitter-bootstrap-modal-how-to-pass-data-to-callback-function)).

b) If the ID of your modal is 'login' as your question suggests, then it's not working because you left out the hash:

```
$('#login').modal('hide');
```